# Expo doesn't recognize .d.ts files

Tags: react-native, expo

That's the error:

```
Unable to resolve module '../../@types/layout' from 'layout/tabs/container.tsx'
None of these files exist:
  * @types/layout(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
  * @types/layout/index(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
```

I tried to add in `metro.config.js`:

```
sourceExts: ['js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx', 'd.ts'],
```

but that doesn't resolve the problem, and i didn't find a solution